# Keep current bootstrap menu open when the input is on focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have many (dynamic) input with each having its own dropdown

I want to keep the dropdown popup in focus when the current input is active/being typed , now the issue is my dropdown menu closes when I type in textbox

**I cannot use ID selector and hard code since the number of dropdowns are dynamic.**

I have tried with

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.."  class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
    
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.."  class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
            
    
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script>
$(function(){

  $('.dropdown-item').click(function(e){
var value = $(this).data('value');
var textElement = $(this).parent().parent().prev()
textElement = textElement.val(textElement.val() + value);
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
textElement.focus()
  });
  
});


$(".search").keyup(function(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $(this).get(0);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = $(this).parent().get(0);

  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  a[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  a[i].style.display = "none";
}
  }
});

(function() {
var disable = false;
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
        disable = true;
        console.log("inside1")
    })
    .on('focus', function() {
        if (!disable) {
            $(this).dropdown('toggle');            console.log("inside2")
        }
    })
    .on('mouseup touchend',function() {
        disable = false;console.log("inside3")
    })
})()

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might need to explain how this is meant to work: "*I want to keep the dropdown popup **in focus** when the current input is active/being typed*" - if the dropdown is in *focus* then it *is* the "active" input.  You can't have two active inputs / two inputs with focus at the same time.  You might have meant "keep the dropdown *visible*".

Comment: When I click inputbox 1, the associated dropdown must be opened automatcially, currently I need to click dropdown toggle. Please note that the question has been revised since the time you checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".input-group > input")
    .on("focus", (e) => {
      let inputEl = e.currentTarget;
      let dropdownEl = inputEl.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
      $(dropdownEl).show();
    })
    .on("blur", (e) => {
      // If click outside the input, check for condition to hide the dropdown
      let inputEl = e.currentTarget;
      let dropdownEl = inputEl.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
      let dropdownSearchEl = dropdownEl.querySelector('.search');
      if (e.relatedTarget == dropdownSearchEl) {
        // Check if the target is the input insdie dropdown, then return to prevent the dropdown hiding
        return;
      }
      $(dropdownEl).hide();
    })
    .on('keyup', (e) => {
      let inputEl = e.currentTarget;
      let dropdownEl = inputEl.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
      let dropdownSearchEl = dropdownEl.querySelector('.search');

      // Un-comment here if you want to set the value of the dropdown input as the value of the actual input
      // dropdownSearchEl.value = inputEl.value;
    });

  $(".search")
    .on("blur", (e) => {
      // When click outside the dropdown search input, hide the dropdown
      let dropdownInputEl = e.currentTarget;
      let dropdownEl = dropdownInputEl.parentElement;
      $(dropdownEl).hide();
    })
    .on("keyup", function() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = $(this).get(0);
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      div = $(this).parent().get(0);

      a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
    <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="search">
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
    <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search">
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
    <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search">
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Since you are using Bootstrap dropdown, you can use its `Popover` methods to toggle show/hide the dropdown [Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/).
The steps I do to achieve what you want:

1. Assign event `focus` and `blur` on the `input` to show/hide the dropdown. Inside the `blur` event, I check for the condition if the user click on the dropdown's input, then still keep the dropdown opening
2. Assign the event `blur` on the dropdown input to hide the dropdown

Ps: Using the jQuery `event` you can get the related DOM element, to experiment a little bit further, you can log the event then use the Devtool to look for the element you want to get. As you can see, in the script, I use `event.currentTarget` to get the element that the user click on. That's solve the problem.